# Create a list of matrices with a loop and merging them in R

Tags: r, list, loops, matrix

I have several matrices, lets make it simple and say I have 3 matrices. I want to create a list of them and then use rbind to put one over the other. 
If I do it by hand, using the following code, it works:

```
list<-list(matrix1,matrix2,matrix3)
test<-do.call("rbind",list)
```

and I get a matrix of 97947 rows by 4 columns which is what I want. 
but if I do a loop, it does not work:

```
list2<-list()
for (i in 1:3)
{
y<-paste0("matrix",x)
list2[[x]] <- y
}
test2<-do.call("rbind",list2)
```

And I get a 3x1 character matrix ???
Can someone please point me to the error? 
Any comments would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!!!!

Comment: I know this might seem an annoying comment, but what is wrong with the first method?! Far more efficient. I sense you may have a lot of matrices and want an automated method of getting them into the list in the first place. Try `list <- mget( ls( pattern = paste0( "matrix , 1:3 ) ) )`

Comment: @SimonO101 I'm guessing I'm not the only one who didn't test my code. ;)

Comment: @Dr.Mike Dammit you are totally right. Sorry, no pattern matching required here. If you have a set of sequential names for your matrices you just need to do the even easier `list <- mget( paste0( "matrix" , 1:3 ) )`

Comment: Thanks so much! you are right, it is so much easier with mget, thanks SO much!!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

Consider using a function like `mget` to *get* all of your matrix objects from the `globalenvironment` (the default environment) and put them in a list. You can then use your `do.call` method and avoid the loop. Here is a toy example:

```
#  Some data
m1 <- matrix( 1:4 , 2 , byrow = TRUE )
m2 <- matrix( 1:4 , 2 , byrow = TRUE )
m3 <- matrix( 1:4 , 2 , byrow = TRUE )

#  Use mget to put them in a list. mget searches the .GlobalEnvironment (by default) for the object names in it's first argument
list <- mget( paste0( "m" , 1:3 ) )
list
#$m1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    3    4

#$m2
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    3    4

#$m3
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    3    4

#  rbind them
do.call( rbind , list )
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    3    4
#[3,]    1    2
#[4,]    3    4
#[5,]    1    2
#[6,]    3    4
```

Comment: @user2917283 Glad I could help. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon - I'm seeing an error message when I run "list <- mget( paste0( "m" , 1:3 ) )": **Error in mget(paste0("m", 1:3)) : argument "envir" is missing, with no default.**